# EF delete entity with many to many relationship to itself / optional many-to-many

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an entity `site` that has a concept of a "buddy site". So I have that defined as a many-to-many relationship to itself

```
public class Site : Base
{
    public DateTime EstablishedDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Site> Buddies { get; set; }
}
```

Config:

```
public SiteConfig()
{
    HasMany(x => x.Buddies).WithMany();
}
```

This works until I try to delete a `site` that has buddy sites, at which point i get the referential constraint error. How do I define the many to many relationship to be optional (0 to many)?

Comment: Is your many-to-many junction table a a 1st class member of the `Context`?

Comment: My many to many table isn't explicitly defined in `Context`. It only exists as `EF` auto-generated table.

Comment: If you explicitly manage the many-to-many table on the context, you could use a cascade delete to remove the entry in the junction table automatically when one of the associated Sites is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `Clear` method before saving changes:

```
var site=Context.Sites.FirstOrDefault();
site.Buddies.Clear();// remove relationship but not entities
Context.Sites.Remove(site);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This works, thank you, but I can't shake the feeling that this isn't the best way. In my particular case the entity comes from an API layer so it's disconnected. I have to attach the entity and load the `buddies` JUST to clear them in the next line. I hope there is some better configuration related solution.